# Why is Blu-Ray File Read Speed (Data Transfer) slower than Write Speed?

Tags: performance, blu-ray

I burnt a full Blu-ray disc (25GB) at 8x speed. It took some 20 or so minutes, but when I try to copy it back to my computer to verify the contents via Windows explorer, it takes over 2 hours and says it is copying at 1.5MB/s-2.3MB/s. Why is it so slow? That isn't even 1x Blu-ray speed, which according to wiki is 4.5MB/s. Any clue how I can improve my speed?

Not sure if any of this matters but here are some details:

- Windows 8
- Burnt using BurnAway Free
- Reading using standard Windows Explorer
- The Blu-ray drive is an [LG WH12LS30](https://www.newegg.com/lg-wh12ls30-internal-blu-ray-burner/p/N82E16827136226)

Answer (score 0):

25 GB divided by 1200 seconds yields 20 MB/s which is
about 4x effective speed. So probably Defect Management
was enabled when the disc was written, unless your 
computer was incabable of delivering the data stream
at higher speed.

Defect Management checkreads the written blocks as
long as they are in the drive buffer. In case of poor
readability, it relocates such a block to the Spare Area
at the inner rim of the medium.
Such relocations can make reading quite slow.
In any case, Defect Management halves write speed.

You could try whether your burn software offers a feature
to disable Defect Management resp. enable Stream Recording
resp. enable Real-Time Recording. If this burns at 8x
effective speed, and if the read speed is still slow, then
the drive simply has a hard time to read blocks.